# How do I check the size of different variables in a function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, sizeof

For a class I have to this simple problem in which I need to check the size of multiple types of variables while using pointers and display it all.
I want my code to look as clean as posible. So I wanted to know if there is something that does it cleaner. I have this code as of now.

```
void size (float *p1, int *p2, int*p3, int *p4, double *p5,bool *pc){
    for(int i=1; i <=5; i++){
        cout << "Size of pointer " << i << " is:" << sizeof(p::i)<< endl;
    }

    cout << "Size of control pointer is:" << sizeof(pc)<< endl;
}
```

Is there a way to do it somehow like this, or do I have to explicitely write line by line?

Comment: Cleanest way *would be* to write it line by line. Any attempt to get at a loop will only complicate matters, and make your code harder to read.

Comment: If you have the option, you should use `std::vector<float>` and `std::vector<int>` as argument instead of raw pointers. If you can't do that, you have pass the sizes of the array in separate argument(s).

Comment: Even if there was, that would only give you the size of the pointers, not what they point to. Not super interesting for plain pointers.

Comment: Note: The size of a pointer is pretty much always the same not matter what type it points to. If you are trying to get the size of an array pointed at, this is not the way.

Comment: What is `p::i` supposed to mean? Did you think that it would turn that into `p1` when `i == 1`?

Comment: `p::i` would **never** refer to `p1` as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template parameter packs to do this, but it's not clear this is the best choice for whatever problem you're facing.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void print_size(const T* t) {
  std::cout << sizeof(*t)  << '\n';
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print_size(const T* t, Args... args) {
  std::cout << sizeof(*t)  << '\n';
  print_size(args...);
}

struct MyStruct {
  const char my_char[10];
};

int main() {
  int* int_ptr;
  double* double_ptr;
  MyStruct* my_struct;
  print_size(int_ptr, double_ptr, my_struct);
}
```

Results in the output (on my machine):

```
4
8
10
```

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to automatically print the sizes of some function parameters, you may write something like

```
template< typename T, typename... V >
void print_size_of_args( T(*f)(V...) )
  {(( std::cout << "size of arg[" << typeid(V).name() << "] is " << sizeof(V) << std::endl ), ... );}

void fun(float *p1, int *p2, int*p3, int *p4, double *p5,bool *pc)
{
  print_size_of_args(fun);
  // ...
}
```

this is c++17 and, as it is, works for non overloaded, non member functions; can be made more general if necessary ...